# Wait for child functions to execute before returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, es6-promise, google-sheets-api

So I have this script that renames files on Google Drive.
It reads two columns from Google Spreadsheet, containing fileID and filename.
Finds the files with fileId on Google Drive, and renames it with the filename from the sheet.
Everything is working fine. To make it easier and available as a route in an API, I exported it.

The problem is, the main module.exports.rename() function has all these child functions that are being executed. It doesn't wait for the execution and renaming and just returns a response.
It just returns the message "Renamed 1 Files Successfully !", since the counter `ctr` is initially 1.

I tried to use a boolean variable, set as false. Then set it true in the getSheetandBatchRename(), and added an if statement above return for the main function. But that doesn't work of course.

I think I am missing something fundamental here.
What is the right way to achieve this?

```
module.exports.rename = async function(req, res) {
  const fs = require("fs");
  const readline = require("readline");
  const { google } = require("googleapis");

  // If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
  const SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"
  ];
  // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
  // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
  // time.
  const PATH = "./server/components/scripts/renamingTool/";
  const TOKEN_PATH = PATH + "token.json";

  let taskDone = false;

  // Load client secrets from a local file.
  fs.readFile(PATH + "credentials.json", (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log("Error loading client secret file:", err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), getSheetandBatchRename);
  });

  /**
   * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
   * given callback function.
   * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
   * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
   */
  function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id,
      client_secret,
      redirect_uris[0]
    );

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
   * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
   * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
   * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
   */
  function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: "offline",
      scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url:", authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", code => {
      rl.close();
      oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return console.error("Error retrieving access token", err);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
        // Store the token to disk for later program executions
        fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), err => {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          console.log("Token stored to", TOKEN_PATH);
        });
        callback(oAuth2Client);
      });
    });
  }

  async function getSheetandBatchRename(auth) {
    try {
      const data = await getSheet(auth);
      console.log("Number of inventories : " + data.length);
      taskDone = true;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("getSheetandBatchRename");
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  function updateExt(ext) {
    // to solve if ther were some problems
    if (ext === "1" || ext === "0" || ext === "2" || ext === " Aula 2")
      ext = "jpg";
    return ext;
  }

  function getSheet(auth) {
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
        {
          spreadsheetId: "1QV3ZshFNVrPCSvMP1O0KjXTcx5pfQMNuNeFbku-TKm4",
          range: "Final!A2:B"
        },
        async (err, res) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          let data = res.data.values;
          try {
            for (const [i, el] of data.entries()) {
              let filename = await getafile(auth, el[0], i);
              if (filename !== -1) {
                let ext = filename.split(".");
                ext = ext[ext.length - 1];
                // ext = updateExt(ext);
                let newName = el[1] + "." + ext;
                await renameafile(auth, el[0], i, newName);
              }
            }
          } catch (err) {
            console.log("getSheet");
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve(data);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  let ctr = 1;
  function getafile(auth, fileId, i) {
    if (fileId === -1) return -1;
    const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      drive.files.get(
        {
          fileId: fileId
        },
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          if (res.status !== 200) {
            reject("Status Code : " + res.status);
          }
          let filename = res.data.name;
          // console.log(ctr + "\t" + fileId + "\t" + filename);
          ctr++;
          resolve(filename);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  function renameafile(auth, fileId, i, newName) {
    const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      drive.files.update(
        {
          fileId: fileId,
          resource: {
            name: newName
          }
        },
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          if (res.status !== 200) {
            reject("Status Code : " + res.status);
          }
          let filename = res.data.name;
          console.log(i + 1 + "\t" + fileId + "\t" + filename);
          resolve(filename);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "Renamed " + ctr + " Files Successfully !",
    status: 200
  });
};
```

Comment: Because `fs.readfile` executes asynchronously and you are not waiting for it.

Comment: Thanks @M1K1O. That was it, the fundamental thing I was missing.
Could you write this as an answer so I could mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fs.readFile`, which is asynchronous, as noted by [M1K1O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113204/m1k1o) in the comments.

If you're using node 10 or more, You can use `fs.promises.readFile` and `await` its result, so it will wait for its return before continuing the execution or your program.

Comment: I ended up using fs.readFileSync everywhere instead of fs.readFile and added await before callbacks, that solved the problem.